# Can I use an 12v 6Ah drill battery to power an 8amp pump?

Tags: batteries, amperage

https://www.screwfix.com/p/milwaukee-m12-b6-12v-6-0ah-li-ion-redlithium-battery/674FJ?tc=VB8

Is it safe/possible to convert this to be used with an electric circuit to power an 12V 8A water pump?

They have 12V DC output adapters, but they are limited to around 2A output:

https://www.milwaukeetool.eu/en-eu/m12-compact-charger-and-power-source/m12-tc/

I've read electric drills draw between 4-8A, so would it be safe just to connect this battery directly to the circuit?

Would I have heat issues from drawing 8A continually until 100% of the battery is spent?

Thanks.

Comment: If it's a 6 A·h battery and you pull 8 amps from it, you're not going to be able to run for an hour in the first place!

Comment: You're not going to be able to draw 8A for an hour from a 6Ah battery.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?  This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.  If you really want to power a 12V pump from the wall, just say so -- we'll help you.  If you really want to power a 12V pump from a battery for an hour, just say so -- we'll help you.  BTW: please *edit your question* with any new information.  Cuz -- Stackexchange.

Comment: @Hearth Thats what I mean - if I draw 100% of the batteries capacity at 8 amps. It's  not exactly an hour, but the pumps draw would only be approximately 8 amps too.

Comment: @TimWescott I want to power a remote pump that draws 8 amps continually until the battery is spent. I do not think the other details matter?

Comment: Well, *now that your story has changed*, yes, this can maybe be done.  The remaining question -- which I don't know the answer to -- is does Milwaukie put the low-voltage shutoff in the battery (in which case you just connect battery to pump and enjoy), or in the drill (in which case you need a low-voltage shutoff, or you'll only use each battery once).

Comment: I think my pump controller has a low voltage shut off, would this also protect the battery from getting damaged? (the pump controller will turn the pump off when the battery is low, but I have no idea how accurate it is).

Comment: It is never going to work the way you want it to because that battery is only going to want to run with a milwaukee tool. Just buy some other 12V battery that doesn't have as much crap to interfere with your intended use.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/LiFePO4-Battery-Miady-Rechargeable-Maintenance-free/dp/B07X5G2FFW/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&hvadid=78065330898808&hvbmt=bb&hvdev=c&hvqmt=p&keywords=lfp+battery&qid=1609286106&sr=8-4&tag=mh0b-20

Comment: refer to the battery datasheet to find out the actual expected runtime with a 6 A load ... some manufacturers may determine the 6 Ah rating by draining the battery at 300 mA over 20 hours ... such a battery may last only 40 minutes with a 6 A load

Answer (score 2):

The second question is easy, so I'll answer it first.  A battery with a capacity of 6 Ah store 6 "amp hours" of energy.  This means it could power 6 amps for 1 hour, 12 amps for 0.5 hours, 3 amps for 2 hours, etc.  If you want 8 amps continuously, it can power it for 6Ah/8A = 2/3 h = 40 minutes.  Thus, by physics, it will not be possible to use this batter to power the pump for a full hour.  You will run it dry.

Safety is a more complex issue.  You need to be certain that the batteries are able to source that current for a long period of time.  The information you need is not found in the info you listed.  You need to find a max current rating for it.  I did not find any official sources (so take this with a grain of salt), but I did find a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/MilwaukeePowerTools/comments/efq279/milwaukee_m18_m12_batteries_and_differences/) which identified the actual lithium ion cells used in the M12 series, and their limits

> Now let's dive in. Milwaukee uses Samsung INR18650-30Q cells in their M12 6Ah batteries. Watch ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLUx2-uYdZc ) if you are a nonbeliever. The datasheet specifies it's maximum recommended current draw is 15A per cell. Can the cell provide 20A, or even 30A? Absolutely, it will just get really hot which will permanently reduce it's lifespan and in extreme cases permanently lower the capacity. The battery has 6 cells, 2 banks of 3 series cells. Putting cells in parallel adds up their capacity and max output current. Putting batteries in series adds up their voltage. The cells are 4.2V 3Ah cells.

You are using about half of the maximum recommended current draw.  There's a high likelihood that this is "safe."  I have to fall short of saying "its safe" because the reddit post did not link to a spec sheet that defined what "maximum recommended current draw" was -- whether it was continuous or assuming some nominal duty cycle.  Normal use of these products in workshop tools are obviously not 100% duty cycle.  However, coming up at half of the recommended current draw is a pretty reasonable safety margin to at least start with.  If you truly care about the safety of the device, get the real stats.

Comment: Thanks, the video is really useful